# waitress-serve is not recognized as an internal or external command using nssm

Tags: python, windows, flask, nssm

I'm using nssm to run a flask application. To run flask application I use waitress-serve. In a machine with windows 10, the service maked with nssm works well but in a machine with windows 7 (32 bits) the service doesn't work. The log says "waitress-serve is not recognized as an internal or external command".
I don't know what the problem could be, does anyone have an idea?

Move the windows 7 application to the windows 10 machine and if it works.

This is the code of the bat file that I use with nssm:

```
waitress-serve --port=8081 hello:app
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It was a permissions error, I had to run the service with local admin account.